# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin Android Emulator not starting

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android, hyper-v, visual-studio-emulator

I'm trying to run Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2015

what i selected from debug is Marshmallow 6.0.0 Android 6.0 API23

Android Emulator shows up but gives following error. Please help

[image]

Hyper V shows following

[image]